# boolean from a form(VB.net) insert into a SQl DB

Tags: vb.net

How,in VB.net 2010, a checked checkbox(boolean) from a form to insert as a string in an SQL database like a character `"T"` or `"F"`

Comment: Tsk, tsk. You should be using a bit column.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim value as string = "F"
If checkbox.checked then
    value = "T"
end if
```

Then use `value` in your database operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise way of putting it:

```
Dim theStringToUse as string = iif(theCheckbox.checked, "T", "F").ToString()
```

And in case this isn't clear, here's what you do with it:

```
' assume conn = an open SqlConnection
Dim cmd as new SqlCommand("Insert into TableA (theStringColumn) " & _ 
    "values (@theStringValue)", conn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theStringValue", theStringToUse)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score -1):

When you first dim `value` the string should equal `String.Empty` so you can insert an empty string if the condition is false. Then in your if statement, `value` should equal whatever you want the true condition to equal.

Comment: He wants the false condition to be `"F"`, not `""`